# How to include External classes for extensions in TYPO3?

Tags: php, class, typo3

I have an extension named `Menu` which requires the help of the class `MenuHelper` in the folder `ext/menu/Classes/Helper`.

How do I use it in my controller? The class 'MenuHelper' is being accessed only when it is in the controller folder.

I want to use it in my controller like this :

```
public function listAction() {

        $menugenerators=new MenuHelper(); # Will return something 

        $this->view->assign('menugenerators', $menugenerators);
}
```

Comment: Which TYPO3 version? There are several ways using defined names or Namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place a class in the directory `yourExt/Classes/Helper/NestedDirectory/MenuHelper.php` you have two ways to get the class in all other extbase files.

First way with TYPO3 > 6.0: Using namespaces

```php
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourExtension\Helper\NestedDirectory;

class MenuHelper {
}

?>
```

Now you can make an instance of this class using

```
$menuHelper = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance("YourVendor\\YourExtension\\Helper\\NestedDirectory\\MenuHelper")
```

or simply by using

```
$menuHelper = new \YourVendor\YourExtension\Helper\NestedDirectory\MenuHelper();
```

---

Second way with TYPO3 <= 4.7

```
<?php

class Tx_YourExtension_Helper_NestedDirectory_MenuHelper {
}

?>
```

Now you can make an instance of this class using

```
$menuHelper = t3lib_div::makeInstance("Tx_YourExtension_Helper_NestedDirectory_MenuHelper")
```

or simply by using

```
$menuHelper = new Tx_YourExtension_Helper_NestedDirectory_MenuHelper();
```

The name of the class directs the class-loader to the correct path of the source file. It is very important that the file has the same name the class has.